# get text of selected option by looking for data-attribute

Tags: javascript, html, select, custom-data-attribute

I want to get the text of a selected option from a select element. I know I can make this work by using this:

```
let e = document.getElementById(id)
return e.options[e.selectedIndex].text
```

But I have select-elements without an id but with a data-attribute, e.g. : (they are just placeholders)

```
<select data-statement="1">
           <option>SELECT</option>
           <option>UPDATE</option>
           <option>INSERT</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the selected option text (e.g. into the console.log()) by using the data-attribute?
I tried

```
var countStatement = document.querySelectorAll('[data-statement]');
console.log(countStatment);
```

That doesnt work.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? :)

Background information for maybe better understanding:
I create some select elements by clicking on a button. After that they get filled with different data. In the end I want to display the selected options in an input element. I can do this by giving every single element an Id but thats quite a work-around in my opinion :D

If you have better ways to implement my wanted features, let me know ;) (maybe data-attributes are not meant to be used for this kind of problem)

PS: I am new to programming so be kind if I have not read every documentation of javascript  :D

Comment: `var countStatement = document.querySelector('[data-statement]');`
OR 
`var countStatement = document.querySelectorAll('[data-statement]')[0];`

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a Node-List not a single element.!

Comment: @mplungjan yes it worked. Sry I answered the question of the other guy before I tested your solution. I am sorry for this :)

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it does.